# Not able to run application usuing MongooseModule.forFeature() in NestJs

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I am using following snippet in my code but it gives compile time error saying Nest can't resolve dependencies of the `xModel` (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the MongooseModule context. :(

**Module**

```
@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'X', schema: XSchema }], 'MyMongooseConnection')],
  controllers: [XController],
  providers: [XService],
  exports: [
    XService,],
})
export class XModule { }
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class XService {
  constructor(@InjectModel('X') private  xModel: Model<IXFace>) {}
}
```

**x.schema.ts**

```
export const XSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  XName: { type: String },
});
```

Note that if I remove 'MyMongooseConnection' from forFeature parameter, it works fine. For information I want to create multiple connection in application and want to tie schema with particular connection.

Answer (score 1):

In your `@InjectModel()` you should do `modelName, connectionName` so that your constructor looks like

```
constructor(@InjectModel('X', 'MyMongooseConnection') private readonly xModel: Model<IXFace>) {}
```

Comment: Sure enough, I assumed it was similar to the TypeORM decorators for Nest. Looks like currently a named database isn't truly an option. Maybe an issue should be raised on the mongoose github for NestJS. Shouldn't be too hard to implement something like Nest's TypeORM's implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately, passing a 2nd argument to @InjectModel() is no longer an option.